# lxml / BeautifulSoup parser warning

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, lxml

Using Python 3, I'm trying to parse ugly HTML (which is not under my control) by using `lxml` with BeautifulSoup as explained here: http://lxml.de/elementsoup.html

Specifically, I want to use `lxml`, but I'd like to use BeautifulSoup because like I said, it's ugly HTML and `lxml` will reject it on its own.

The link above says: "All you need to do is pass it to the fromstring() function:"

```
from lxml.html.soupparser import fromstring
root = fromstring(tag_soup)
```

So that's what I'm doing:

```
URL = 'http://some-place-on-the-internet.com'
html_goo = requests.get(URL).text
root = fromstring(html_goo)
```

It **works** in the sense that I can manipulate the HTML just fine after that. My problem is that every time I run the script, I receive this annoying warning:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bs4/__init__.py:166: UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("html.parser"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

To get rid of this warning, change this:

 BeautifulSoup([your markup])

to this:

 BeautifulSoup([your markup], "html.parser")

  markup_type=markup_type))
```

My problem is perhaps obvious: I'm not instantiating BeautifulSoup myself. I've tried adding the proposed parameter to the `fromstring` function, but that just gives me the error: `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`. Searches online have proven fruitless so far.

I'd like to get rid of that warning message. Help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try `root = lxml.html.soupparser.fromstring(html_goo)` ?

Comment: That won't work because `lxml` is a module. But I tried it, and it gives me: NameError: name 'lxml' is not defined (which I think makes sense)

Comment: can't it be called with `soupparser.fromstring(html_goo)` then ? I'm quite surprised it doesn't work when this is directly from their doc :p

Comment: No, running soupparser.fromstring(...) instead of fromstring(...) yields the same result. I also find this rather strange.

Comment: Did you also try `tostring(body, method="html")`?
I'm sorry I probably can't help you much more, everything ran pretty much out of the box when I had used it :/

Comment: @Antry: Not sure what you mean, haven't seen that way before. I've tried lots of other ways of doing this that are probably too exchausting to mention. But I've found the solution by reading the source code of lxml and BeautifulSoup, and posted the solution below. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: No problem ! ^^ Your solution pretty much uses the exact same reasoning as my last comment, where you can pass constructor parameters through fromstring(), good on you for finding a solution ! Good luck with the rest !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had to read `lxml`'s and BeautifulSoup's source code to figure this out.

I'm posting my own answer here, in case someone else may need it in the future.

The `fromstring` function in question is defined so:

```
def fromstring(data, beautifulsoup=None, makeelement=None, **bsargs):
```

The `**bsargs` arguments ends up being sent forward to the BeautifulSoup constructor, which is called like so (in another function, `_parse`):

```
tree = beautifulsoup(source, **bsargs)
```

The BeautifulSoup constructor is defined so:

```
def __init__(self, markup="", features=None, builder=None,
             parse_only=None, from_encoding=None, exclude_encodings=None,
             **kwargs):
```

Now, back to the warning in the question, which is recommending that the argument "html.parser" be added to BeautifulSoup's contructor. According to this, that would be the argument named `features`.

Since the `fromstring` function will pass on named arguments to BeautifulSoup's constructor, we can specify the parser by naming the argument to the `fromstring` function, like so:

```
root = fromstring(clean, features='html.parser')
```

Poof. The warning disappears.

Answer (score 18):

For others init like:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
```

Use

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
```

instead

Answer (score 2):

While using the BeautifulSoup, we always do the things like below:

`[variable] = BeautifulSoup([contents you want to analyze])`

Here is the problem:

If you have installed "lxml" before, BeautifulSoup will automatically notice that it used it as the praser. It's not the error, just a notification.

So how to remove it?

Just do this like below:

`[variable] = BeautifulSoup([contents you want to analyze], features = "lxml")`

> "Based on the latest version of BeautifulSoup, 4.6.3"

Notice that different versions of BeautifulSoup have different ways, or the grammar, to add this pattern, just look at the notice message carefully.

Good luck!

Comment: if your content is XML use this `soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content_in_xml, 'lxml')`, if your content is html use this `soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')`