# Getting empty list when scraping web page content using xpath in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, python-requests, lxml

When i try to import some data using xpath from the url in the following code i get an empty list:

```
    import requests
    from lxml import html
    
    url = 'https://www.sofascore.com/team/football/palmeiras/1963'
    browsers = {'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 \(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome / 86.0.4240.198Safari / 537.36"}
    page = requests.get(url, headers=browsers)
        
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    elements = tree.xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/span[1]')

    print(elements[0].text)
```

Output:

```
[]
```

What i expect:

```
'Matches'
```

It's for a project that analyzes the behavior of brazilian teams of football, so i want to import all the statistics of each team and create a data frame with those data, but i need to pull all the data from the site first.

Comment: The page looks to be using javascript to load data asynchronously, so you won't be able to do this via a simple requests.get as the call will return before the page has completely loaded - you'll probably need to look into using BeautifulSoup and / or Selenium to accomplish this.

Comment: If you are curious to see which parts of the website did get returned by your request, you could use the following code to save it to an html file:  `with open('my_page.html', 'w',  encoding="utf-8") as f: f.write(page.content.decode("utf-8"))`

Comment: But why when i print the result from "page.content" i receive every data there's in the page (even this specifc string that i'm looking for)? I thought this wasn't a problem since i can return every text when i print the result of "page.content"

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an empty list because `//*[@id="__next"]/div/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/span[1]` XPath locator matches nothing on that page.
Long absolute XPath locators are extremely unreliable and fragile.

Comment: But, in this case, how should i import this specif data withou using full xpath?

Comment: Let me know if Barry the Platipus answer resolved your problem. If not - I need to know what elements(s) you wanted to catch

Comment: It didn't, but i solved the issue using Selenium instead of Requests, like sugested by Allan Elder in coments above

Answer (score 0):

Information in that page is being pulled by javascript (after initial html is loaded, so requests cannot see subsequent info) by accessing various API endpoints. You can see those APIs under Network Tab in Dev tools.
Here is an example of scraping one such API endpoint (not sure if it's the one serving the info you're after, you can try the others as well):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}

url = 'https://api.sofascore.com/api/v1/team/1963/events/last/0'

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
df = pd.json_normalize(r.json()['events'])
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
customId    winnerCode  hasGlobalHighlights hasEventPlayerStatistics    hasEventPlayerHeatMap   id  homeRedCards    startTimestamp  slug    finalResultOnly tournament.name tournament.slug tournament.category.name    tournament.category.slug    tournament.category.sport.name  tournament.category.sport.slug  tournament.category.sport.id    tournament.category.id  tournament.category.flag    tournament.category.alpha2  tournament.uniqueTournament.name    tournament.uniqueTournament.slug    tournament.uniqueTournament.category.name   tournament.uniqueTournament.category.slug   tournament.uniqueTournament.category.sport.name tournament.uniqueTournament.category.sport.slug tournament.uniqueTournament.category.sport.id   tournament.uniqueTournament.category.id tournament.uniqueTournament.category.flag   tournament.uniqueTournament.category.alpha2 tournament.uniqueTournament.userCount   tournament.uniqueTournament.hasPositionGraph    tournament.uniqueTournament.id  tournament.uniqueTournament.hasEventPlayerStatistics    tournament.uniqueTournament.displayInverseHomeAwayTeams tournament.priority tournament.id   roundInfo.round status.code status.description  status.type homeTeam.name   homeTeam.slug   homeTeam.shortName  homeTeam.gender homeTeam.sport.name homeTeam.sport.slug homeTeam.sport.id   homeTeam.userCount  homeTeam.nameCode   homeTeam.disabled   homeTeam.national   homeTeam.type   homeTeam.id homeTeam.subTeams   homeTeam.teamColors.primary homeTeam.teamColors.secondary   homeTeam.teamColors.text    awayTeam.name   awayTeam.slug   awayTeam.shortName  awayTeam.gender awayTeam.sport.name awayTeam.sport.slug awayTeam.sport.id   awayTeam.userCount  awayTeam.nameCode   awayTeam.disabled   awayTeam.national   awayTeam.type   awayTeam.id awayTeam.subTeams   awayTeam.teamColors.primary awayTeam.teamColors.secondary   awayTeam.teamColors.text    homeScore.current   homeScore.display   homeScore.period1   homeScore.period2   homeScore.normaltime    awayScore.current   awayScore.display   awayScore.period1   awayScore.period2   awayScore.normaltime    time.injuryTime1    time.injuryTime2    time.currentPeriodStartTimestamp    changes.changes changes.changeTimestamp coverage    awayRedCards    roundInfo.name  roundInfo.slug  roundInfo.cupRoundType  aggregatedWinnerCode    previousLegEventId  homeScore.aggregated    awayScore.aggregated    homeScore.penalties awayScore.penalties
0   nOsHO   2   True    True    True    10114138    1.0 1655067600  coritiba-palmeiras  False   Brasileiro Serie A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  Brasileiro Série A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  241156  True    325 True    False   266 83  11  100 Ended   finished    Coritiba    coritiba    Coritiba    M   Football    football    1   29502   COR False   False   0   1982    []  #ffffff #009966 #009966 Palmeiras   palmeiras   Palmeiras   M   Football    football    1   184430  PAL False   False   0   1963    []  #339966 #336633 #336633 0   0   0.0 0.0 0   2   2   1.0 1.0 2   2   10.0    1655074949  [status.code, status.description, status.type, homeScore.period2, homeScore.normaltime, awayScore.period2, awayScore.normaltime, time.currentPeriodStart]   1655074952  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   nOsoWc  1   True    True    True    10113875    NaN 1655413200  atletico-goianiense-palmeiras   False   Brasileiro Serie A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  Brasileiro Série A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  241156  True    325 True    False   266 83  12  100 Ended   finished    Palmeiras   palmeiras   Palmeiras   M   Football    football    1   184430  PAL False   False   0   1963    []  #339966 #336633 #336633 Atlético Goianiense atletico-goianiense Atlético-GO M   Football    football    1   32941   GOI False   False   0   7314    []  #ff0000 #000000 #000000 4   4   4.0 0.0 4   2   2   1.0 1.0 2   4   4.0 1655419980  [status.code, status.description, status.type, homeScore.period2, homeScore.normaltime, awayScore.period2, awayScore.normaltime, time.currentPeriodStart]   1655419982  1.0 1.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   nOsGO   2   True    True    True    10113937    NaN 1655766000  sao-paulo-palmeiras False   Brasileiro Serie A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  Brasileiro Série A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  241156  True    325 True    False   266 83  13  100 Ended   finished    São Paulo   sao-paulo   São Paulo   M   Football    football    1   137748  SPA False   False   0   1981    []  #ffffff #000000 #000000 Palmeiras   palmeiras   Palmeiras   M   Football    football    1   184430  PAL False   False   0   1963    []  #339966 #336633 #336633 1   1   1.0 0.0 1   2   2   0.0 2.0 2   3   7.0 1655773291  [status.code, status.description, status.type, homeScore.period2, homeScore.normaltime, awayScore.period2, awayScore.normaltime, time.currentPeriodStart]   1655773295  1.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   nOsGO   1   True    True    True    10366721    NaN 1656025200  sao-paulo-palmeiras False   Copa do Brasil  copa-do-brasil  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  Copa do Brasil  copa-do-brasil  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  119429  False   373 False   False   0   283 8   100 Ended   finished    São Paulo   sao-paulo   São Paulo   M   Football    football    1   137748  SPA False   False   0   1981    []  #ffffff #000000 #000000 Palmeiras   palmeiras   Palmeiras   M   Football    football    1   184430  PAL False   False   0   1963    []  #339966 #336633 #336633 1   1   1.0 0.0 1   0   0   0.0 0.0 0   2   5.0 1656032409  [homeScore.period2, awayScore.period2]  1657698656  -1.0    NaN Round of 16 round-of-16 8.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4   nOspWc  3   True    True    True    10113904    NaN 1656270000  avai-palmeiras  False   Brasileiro Serie A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  Brasileiro Série A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  241156  True    325 True    False   266 83  14  100 Ended   finished    Avaí    avai    Avaí    M   Football    football    1   20083   AVA False   False   0   7315    []  #0066ff #ffffff #ffffff Palmeiras   palmeiras   Palmeiras   M   Football    football    1   184430  PAL False   False   0   1963    []  #339966 #336633 #336633 2   2   1.0 1.0 2   2   2   0.0 2.0 2   5   5.0 1656277177  [homeScore.period2, awayScore.period2]  1665242507  1.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
5   nOsQuc  2   True    True    True    10341622    NaN 1656540900  cerro-porteno-palmeiras False   CONMEBOL Libertadores, Knockout stage   conmebol-libertadores-knockout-stage    South America   south-america   Football    football    1   1470    south-america   NaN CONMEBOL Libertadores   conmebol-libertadores   South America   south-america   Football    football    1   1470    south-america   NaN 185738  False   384 True    False   465 309 8   100 Ended   finished    Cerro Porteño   cerro-porteno   Cerro Porteño   M   Football    football    1   19852   CPO NaN False   0   5991    []  #cc0000 #003366 #003366 Palmeiras   palmeiras   Palmeiras   M   Football    football    1   184430  PAL False   False   0   1963    []  #339966 #336633 #336633 0   0   0.0 0.0 0   3   3   0.0 3.0 3   2   4.0 1656547691  [homeScore.period2, awayScore.period2]  1662625197  1.0 NaN Round of 16 round-of-16 8.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
6   nOsrO   2   True    True    True    10114178    1.0 1656806400  athletico-palmeiras False   Brasileiro Serie A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  Brasileiro Série A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  241156  True    325 True    False   266 83  15  100 Ended   finished    Palmeiras   palmeiras   Palmeiras   M   Football    football    1   184430  PAL False   False   0   1963    []  #339966 #336633 #336633 Athletico   athletico   Athletico   M   Football    football    1   57052   CAP False   False   0   1967    []  #000000 #cc0000 #cc0000 0   0   0.0 0.0 0   2   2   1.0 1.0 2   3   7.0 1656813370  [homeScore.period2, awayScore.period2]  1665242508  1.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7   nOsQuc  1   True    True    True    10341627    NaN 1657145700  cerro-porteno-palmeiras False   CONMEBOL Libertadores, Knockout stage   conmebol-libertadores-knockout-stage    South America   south-america   Football    football    1   1470    south-america   NaN CONMEBOL Libertadores   conmebol-libertadores   South America   south-america   Football    football    1   1470    south-america   NaN 185738  False   384 True    False   465 309 8   100 Ended   finished    Palmeiras   palmeiras   Palmeiras   M   Football    football    1   184430  PAL False   False   0   1963    []  #339966 #336633 #336633 Cerro Porteño   cerro-porteno   Cerro Porteño   M   Football    football    1   19852   CPO NaN False   0   5991    []  #cc0000 #003366 #003366 5   5   1.0 4.0 5   0   0   0.0 0.0 0   2   2.0 1657152360  [homeScore.period2, awayScore.period2]  1662625197  1.0 NaN Round of 16 round-of-16 8.0 1.0 10341622.0  8.0 0.0 NaN NaN
8   nOsvP   3   True    True    True    10114100    NaN 1657486800  fortaleza-palmeiras False   Brasileiro Serie A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  Brasileiro Série A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  241156  True    325 True    False   266 83  16  100 Ended   finished    Fortaleza   fortaleza   Fortaleza   M   Football    football    1   57572   FOR False   False   0   2020    []  #0000ff #ff0000 #ff0000 Palmeiras   palmeiras   Palmeiras   M   Football    football    1   184430  PAL False   False   0   1963    []  #339966 #336633 #336633 0   0   0.0 0.0 0   0   0   0.0 0.0 0   5   NaN 1657495856  [homeScore.period2, awayScore.period2]  1665242510  1.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
9   nOsGO   0   True    True    True    10366728    NaN 1657839600  sao-paulo-palmeiras False   Copa do Brasil  copa-do-brasil  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  Copa do Brasil  copa-do-brasil  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  119429  False   373 False   False   0   283 8   120 AP  finished    Palmeiras   palmeiras   Palmeiras   M   Football    football    1   184430  PAL False   False   0   1963    []  #339966 #336633 #336633 São Paulo   sao-paulo   São Paulo   M   Football    football    1   137748  SPA False   False   0   1981    []  #ffffff #000000 #000000 2   2   NaN NaN 2   1   1   NaN NaN 1   3   5.0 1657847241  [homeScore.current, awayScore.current]  1660983567  -1.0    NaN Round of 16 round-of-16 8.0 2.0 10366721.0  2.0 2.0 3.0 4.0
10  nOscJu  1   True    True    True    10114052    NaN 1658185200  cuiaba-palmeiras    False   Brasileiro Serie A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  Brasileiro Série A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  241156  True    325 True    False   266 83  17  100 Ended   finished    Palmeiras   palmeiras   Palmeiras   M   Football    football    1   184430  PAL False   False   0   1963    []  #339966 #336633 #336633 Cuiabá  cuiaba  Cuiabá  M   Football    football    1   24818   CUI False   False   0   49202   []  #ffffff #006600 #006600 1   1   0.0 1.0 1   0   0   0.0 0.0 0   3   5.0 1658192125  [time.currentPeriodStart, status.code, status.description, status.type, homeScore.period2, homeScore.normaltime, awayScore.period2, awayScore.normaltime]   1658192131  1.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
11  nOsyO   2   True    True    True    10113922    NaN 1658444400  america-mineiro-palmeiras   False   Brasileiro Serie A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  Brasileiro Série A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  241156  True    325 True    False   266 83  18  100 Ended   finished    América Mineiro america-mineiro América-MG  M   Football    football    1   33986   AMG False   False   0   1973    []  #056635 #ffffff #ffffff Palmeiras   palmeiras   Palmeiras   M   Football    football    1   184430  PAL False   False   0   1963    []  #339966 #336633 #336633 0   0   0.0 0.0 0   1   1   0.0 1.0 1   2   4.0 1658451192  [status.code, status.description, status.type, homeScore.period2, homeScore.normaltime, awayScore.period2, awayScore.normaltime, time.currentPeriodStart]   1658451194  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
12  nOsqO   1   True    True    True    10114118    NaN 1658689200  internacional-palmeiras False   Brasileiro Serie A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  Brasileiro Série A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  241156  True    325 True    False   266 83  19  100 Ended   finished    Palmeiras   palmeiras   Palmeiras   M   Football    football    1   184430  PAL False   False   0   1963    []  #339966 #336633 #336633 Internacional   internacional   Internacional   M   Football    football    1   75718   INT False   False   0   1966    []  #cc0000 #cc0000 #cc0000 2   2   1.0 1.0 2   1   1   0.0 1.0 1   3   4.0 1658696058  [time.currentPeriodStart, status.code, status.description, status.type, homeScore.period2, homeScore.normaltime, awayScore.period2, awayScore.normaltime]   1658696066  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
13  nOsbP   2   True    True    True    10113779    1.0 1659209400  ceara-palmeiras False   Brasileiro Serie A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  Brasileiro Série A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  241156  True    325 True    False   266 83  20  100 Ended   finished    Ceará   ceara   Ceará   M   Football    football    1   49805   CEA False   False   0   2001    []  #000000 #ffffff #ffffff Palmeiras   palmeiras   Palmeiras   M   Football    football    1   184430  PAL False   False   0   1963    []  #339966 #336633 #336633 1   1   0.0 1.0 1   2   2   2.0 0.0 2   7   8.0 1659216904  [status.code, status.description, status.type, homeScore.period2, homeScore.normaltime, awayScore.period2, awayScore.normaltime, time.currentPeriodStart]   1659216908  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
14  nOsCO   3   True    True    True    10445784    NaN 1659573000  atletico-mineiro-palmeiras  False   CONMEBOL Libertadores, Knockout stage   conmebol-libertadores-knockout-stage    South America   south-america   Football    football    1   1470    south-america   NaN CONMEBOL Libertadores   conmebol-libertadores   South America   south-america   Football    football    1   1470    south-america   NaN 185738  False   384 True    False   465 309 4   100 Ended   finished    Atlético Mineiro    atletico-mineiro    Atlético-MG M   Football    football    1   110163  ATL False   False   0   1977    []  #000000 #ffffff #ffffff Palmeiras   palmeiras   Palmeiras   M   Football    football    1   184430  PAL False   False   0   1963    []  #339966 #336633 #336633 2   2   1.0 1.0 2   2   2   0.0 2.0 2   2   5.0 1659579833  [status.code, status.description, status.type, homeScore.period2, homeScore.normaltime, awayScore.period2, awayScore.normaltime, time.currentPeriodStart]   1659579836  NaN NaN Quarterfinal    quarterfinal    4.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
15  kOsnO   1   True    True    True    10113929    NaN 1659898800  palmeiras-goias False   Brasileiro Serie A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  Brasileiro Série A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  241156  True    325 True    False   266 83  21  100 Ended   finished    Palmeiras   palmeiras   Palmeiras   M   Football    football    1   184430  PAL False   False   0   1963    []  #339966 #336633 #336633 Goiás   goias   Goiás   M   Football    football    1   27727   GGO False   False   0   1960    []  #006633 #ffffff #ffffff 3   3   2.0 1.0 3   0   0   0.0 0.0 0   7   4.0 1659905886  [status.code, status.description, status.type, homeScore.period2, homeScore.normaltime, awayScore.period2, awayScore.normaltime, time.currentPeriodStart]   1659905888  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
16  nOsCO   1   True    True    True    10445780    2.0 1660177800  atletico-mineiro-palmeiras  False   CONMEBOL Libertadores, Knockout stage   conmebol-libertadores-knockout-stage    South America   south-america   Football    football    1   1470    south-america   NaN CONMEBOL Libertadores   conmebol-libertadores   South America   south-america   Football    football    1   1470    south-america   NaN 185738  False   384 True    False   465 309 4   120 AP  finished    Palmeiras   palmeiras   Palmeiras   M   Football    football    1   184430  PAL False   False   0   1963    []  #339966 #336633 #336633 Atlético Mineiro    atletico-mineiro    Atlético-MG M   Football    football    1   110163  ATL False   False   0   1977    []  #000000 #ffffff #ffffff 0   0   NaN NaN 0   0   0   NaN NaN 0   2   5.0 1660185718  [homeScore.normaltime, awayScore.normaltime]    1660185810  NaN 1.0 Quarterfinal    quarterfinal    4.0 1.0 10445784.0  2.0 2.0 NaN NaN
17  hOsnO   2   True    True    True    10113914    NaN 1660428000  palmeiras-corinthians   False   Brasileiro Serie A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  Brasileiro Série A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  241156  True    325 True    False   266 83  22  100 Ended   finished    Corinthians corinthians Corinthians M   Football    football    1   147056  COR False   False   0   1957    []  #ffffff #000000 #000000 Palmeiras   palmeiras   Palmeiras   M   Football    football    1   184430  PAL False   False   0   1963    []  #339966 #336633 #336633 0   0   0.0 0.0 0   1   1   0.0 1.0 1   2   4.0 1660434828  [status.code, status.description, status.type, homeScore.period2, homeScore.normaltime, awayScore.period2, awayScore.normaltime, time.currentPeriodStart]   1660434830  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
18  nOsGuc  3   True    True    True    10114106    NaN 1661108400  flamengo-palmeiras  False   Brasileiro Serie A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  Brasileiro Série A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  241156  True    325 True    False   266 83  23  100 Ended   finished    Palmeiras   palmeiras   Palmeiras   M   Football    football    1   184430  PAL False   False   0   1963    []  #339966 #336633 #336633 Flamengo    flamengo    Flamengo    M   Football    football    1   267868  FLA False   False   0   5981    []  #ff0000 #000000 #000000 1   1   0.0 1.0 1   1   1   1.0 0.0 1   4   5.0 1661115271  [time.currentPeriodStart, status.code, status.description, status.type, homeScore.period2, homeScore.normaltime, awayScore.period2, awayScore.normaltime]   1661115278  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
19  lOsnO   3   True    True    True    10113999    NaN 1661637600  palmeiras-fluminense    False   Brasileiro Serie A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  Brasileiro Série A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  241156  True    325 True    False   266 83  24  100 Ended   finished    Fluminense  fluminense  Fluminense  M   Football    football    1   74968   FLU False   False   0   1961    []  #660000 #006633 #006633 Palmeiras   palmeiras   Palmeiras   M   Football    football    1   184430  PAL False   False   0   1963    []  #339966 #336633 #336633 1   1   1.0 0.0 1   1   1   1.0 0.0 1   3   5.0 1661644648  [time.currentPeriodStart, status.code, status.description, status.type, homeScore.period2, homeScore.normaltime, awayScore.period2, awayScore.normaltime]   1661644654  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
20  nOsrO   1   True    True    True    10583051    1.0 1661905800  athletico-palmeiras False   CONMEBOL Libertadores, Knockout stage   conmebol-libertadores-knockout-stage    South America   south-america   Football    football    1   1470    south-america   NaN CONMEBOL Libertadores   conmebol-libertadores   South America   south-america   Football    football    1   1470    south-america   NaN 185738  False   384 True    False   465 309 2   100 Ended   finished    Athletico   athletico   Athletico   M   Football    football    1   57052   CAP False   False   0   1967    []  #000000 #cc0000 #cc0000 Palmeiras   palmeiras   Palmeiras   M   Football    football    1   184430  PAL False   False   0   1963    []  #339966 #336633 #336633 1   1   1.0 0.0 1   0   0   0.0 0.0 0   1   8.0 1661912725  [status.code, status.description, status.type, homeScore.period2, homeScore.normaltime, awayScore.period2, awayScore.normaltime, time.currentPeriodStart]   1661912728  NaN NaN Semifinal   semifinal   2.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
21  nOsZO   3   True    True    True    10113917    NaN 1662242400  red-bull-bragantino-palmeiras   False   Brasileiro Serie A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  Brasileiro Série A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  241156  True    325 True    False   266 83  25  100 Ended   finished    Red Bull Bragantino red-bull-bragantino RB Bragantino   M   Football    football    1   50450   BRA False   False   0   1999    []  #363636 #d8d8d6 #d8d8d6 Palmeiras   palmeiras   Palmeiras   M   Football    football    1   184430  PAL False   False   0   1963    []  #339966 #336633 #336633 2   2   2.0 0.0 2   2   2   1.0 1.0 2   3   5.0 1662249371  [status.code, status.description, status.type, homeScore.period2, homeScore.normaltime, awayScore.period2, awayScore.normaltime, time.currentPeriodStart]   1662249374  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
22  nOsrO   0   True    True    True    10583052    1.0 1662510600  athletico-palmeiras False   CONMEBOL Libertadores, Knockout stage   conmebol-libertadores-knockout-stage    South America   south-america   Football    football    1   1470    south-america   NaN CONMEBOL Libertadores   conmebol-libertadores   South America   south-america   Football    football    1   1470    south-america   NaN 185738  False   384 True    False   465 309 2   100 Ended   finished    Palmeiras   palmeiras   Palmeiras   M   Football    football    1   184430  PAL False   False   0   1963    []  #339966 #336633 #336633 Athletico   athletico   Athletico   M   Football    football    1   57052   CAP False   False   0   1967    []  #000000 #cc0000 #cc0000 2   2   1.0 1.0 2   2   2   0.0 2.0 2   1   5.0 1662517463  [status.code, status.description, status.type, homeScore.period2, homeScore.normaltime, awayScore.period2, awayScore.normaltime, time.currentPeriodStart]   1662517466  NaN NaN Semifinal   semifinal   2.0 2.0 10583051.0  2.0 3.0 NaN NaN
23  nOsFO   1   True    True    True    10114160    NaN 1662854400  juventude-palmeiras False   Brasileiro Serie A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  Brasileiro Série A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  241156  True    325 True    False   266 83  26  100 Ended   finished    Palmeiras   palmeiras   Palmeiras   M   Football    football    1   184430  PAL False   False   0   1963    []  #339966 #336633 #336633 Juventude   juventude   Juventude   M   Football    football    1   23571   JUV False   False   0   1980    []  #006600 #ffffff #ffffff 2   2   0.0 2.0 2   1   1   0.0 1.0 1   3   4.0 1662861282  [status.code, status.description, status.type, homeScore.period2, homeScore.normaltime, awayScore.period2, awayScore.normaltime, time.currentPeriodStart]   1662861286  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
24  nOstO   1   True    True    True    10114023    1.0 1663536600  santos-palmeiras    False   Brasileiro Serie A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  Brasileiro Série A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  241156  True    325 True    False   266 83  27  100 Ended   finished    Palmeiras   palmeiras   Palmeiras   M   Football    football    1   184430  PAL False   False   0   1963    []  #339966 #336633 #336633 Santos  santos  Santos  M   Football    football    1   78113   SAN False   False   0   1968    []  #ffffff #ffffff #ffffff 1   1   0.0 1.0 1   0   0   0.0 0.0 0   2   6.0 1663543460  [status.code, status.description, status.type, homeScore.period2, homeScore.normaltime, awayScore.period2, awayScore.normaltime, time.currentPeriodStart]   1663543463  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
25  nOsCO   2   True    True    True    10114171    NaN 1664412300  atletico-mineiro-palmeiras  False   Brasileiro Serie A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  Brasileiro Série A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  241156  True    325 True    False   266 83  28  100 Ended   finished    Atlético Mineiro    atletico-mineiro    Atlético-MG M   Football    football    1   110163  ATL False   False   0   1977    []  #000000 #ffffff #ffffff Palmeiras   palmeiras   Palmeiras   M   Football    football    1   184430  PAL False   False   0   1963    []  #339966 #336633 #336633 0   0   0.0 0.0 0   1   1   0.0 1.0 1   1   9.0 1664419409  [status.code, status.description, status.type, homeScore.period2, homeScore.normaltime, awayScore.period2, awayScore.normaltime, time.currentPeriodStart]   1664419411  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
26  iOsnO   2   True    True    True    10114062    NaN 1664838000  palmeiras-botafogo  False   Brasileiro Serie A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  Brasileiro Série A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  241156  True    325 True    False   266 83  29  100 Ended   finished    Botafogo    botafogo    Botafogo    M   Football    football    1   50996   BOT False   False   0   1958    []  #000000 #ffffff #ffffff Palmeiras   palmeiras   Palmeiras   M   Football    football    1   184430  PAL False   False   0   1963    []  #339966 #336633 #336633 1   1   1.0 0.0 1   3   3   2.0 1.0 3   4   5.0 1664844924  [time.currentPeriodStart, status.code, status.description, status.type, homeScore.period2, homeScore.normaltime, awayScore.period2, awayScore.normaltime]   1664844933  NaN 1.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
27  nOsHO   1   True    True    True    10114159    NaN 1665093600  coritiba-palmeiras  False   Brasileiro Serie A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  Brasileiro Série A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  241156  True    325 True    False   266 83  30  100 Ended   finished    Palmeiras   palmeiras   Palmeiras   M   Football    football    1   184430  PAL False   False   0   1963    []  #339966 #336633 #336633 Coritiba    coritiba    Coritiba    M   Football    football    1   29502   COR False   False   0   1982    []  #ffffff #009966 #009966 4   4   2.0 2.0 4   0   0   0.0 0.0 0   3   4.0 1665100390  [status.code, status.description, status.type, homeScore.period2, homeScore.normaltime, awayScore.period2, awayScore.normaltime, time.currentPeriodStart]   1665100395  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
28  nOsoWc  3   True    True    True    10113668    NaN 1665437400  atletico-goianiense-palmeiras   False   Brasileiro Serie A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  Brasileiro Série A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  241156  True    325 True    False   266 83  31  100 Ended   finished    Atlético Goianiense atletico-goianiense Atlético-GO M   Football    football    1   32941   GOI False   False   0   7314    []  #ff0000 #000000 #000000 Palmeiras   palmeiras   Palmeiras   M   Football    football    1   184430  PAL False   False   0   1963    []  #339966 #336633 #336633 1   1   0.0 1.0 1   1   1   0.0 1.0 1   1   4.0 1665444055  [status.code, status.description, status.type, homeScore.period2, homeScore.normaltime, awayScore.period2, awayScore.normaltime, time.currentPeriodStart]   1665444058  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
29  nOsGO   3   True    True    True    10113670    NaN 1665946800  sao-paulo-palmeiras False   Brasileiro Serie A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  Brasileiro Série A  brasileiro-serie-a  Brazil  brazil  Football    football    1   13  brazil  BR  241156  True    325 True    False   266 83  32  100 Ended   finished    Palmeiras   palmeiras   Palmeiras   M   Football    football    1   184430  PAL False   False   0   1963    []  #339966 #336633 #336633 São Paulo   sao-paulo   São Paulo   M   Football    football    1   137748  SPA False   False   0   1981    []  #ffffff #000000 #000000 0   0   0.0 0.0 0   0   0   0.0 0.0 0   4   10.0    1665954058  [status.code, status.description, status.type, homeScore.period2, homeScore.normaltime, awayScore.period2, awayScore.normaltime, time.currentPeriodStart]   1665954061  NaN 2.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

​

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


DRIVER_PATH="YOUR DRIVER PATH"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)

price = []

url = ''
driver.get(url)

content = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

for a in soup.find_all('div',href=False,attrs={'class':'_2Shl1j'}):

    print(a)


This code can be helpful to scrape any data from websites using the page_source. It actually executes str content so need of usage lxml or html.parser. so follow this link 


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50045775/lxml-beautifulsoup-parser-warning
```